# Ubuntu automatically logs out whenever a phone is allowed access to the filesystem

Tags: usb, android, logout, 20.10, smartphone

I recently upgraded to 20.10, and ever since, whenever I manually connect my phone and press "allow" on the prompt for file access, the system automatically logs out.

Logging back in maintains the connection with the device, but the previous sessions seem to have been terminated, and all the apps that were open to quitting.

Why might this happen, and how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl --since="-8 minutes:`

Comment: Typo, `sudo journalctl --since="-8 minutes"`